# How can I reduce the number of vertices on a sphere?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I'm trying to create a mesh like this:

[image]

However, I can't seem to figure out how to reduce the number of vertices like the above ref. I've tried limited dissolve or just straight out deleting them - but I can't get this result:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused about the wording here. You say that you're trying to create a mesh like the one in the first image, but then in the second paragraph you say that you "can't get his result:", as if you were trying to get the result shown in the second image. I looked in the edit history, and it looks like that `:` wasn't there until @PeterMertensen edited it. Perhaps you meant something like "but it doesn't work. Here is what it looks like now:"?

Answer (score 4):

You can select the edge ring, then *Select > Checker Deselect*:

[image]

Then *Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops*:

[image]

And at the end, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to dissolve edges

Answer (score 4):

### The Reconstruction Method

Beginning in edit mode, select one loop on one side of the mesh. *(preferably one that touches an axis.)*
[image: 1]

Delete all but that loop and add a *Screw Modifier.*
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Set *Steps Viewport* to the desired resolution and turn on *Merge* and *Calculate Order.*
[image: 4]

At this point, you can have whatever number of loops you want! Once you have chosen your absolute favorite number, simply apply the modifier and model on!

Answer (score 3):

When you first create the sphere, use the Operator Adjust Panel to lower the number of *Segments*.  The panel shows up in the lower left when you add the object.  You may have to click the triangle to open it.

[image: Operator Adjust Panel showing Segments]

You can also reduce the number of *Rings*, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **Decimate** modifier with un-subdivide option with 2 steps